# how to save normalized df to the desktop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I normalize all the df and I try to save the normalized df to the desktop but I get an error, when I try to save non-normalized df to the desktop, the code works and the file is saved to my desktop.
I add the code here in the picture: [image]

the save path is like this because I want the file to save always on the desktop no matter which PC the program run

Comment: I am not an expert but will desk_dir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'Desktop/normal_z.csv')
do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

The `\n` in `\normal_z.csv` is the escape code for newline character. Windows does not allow newline in a file's name.

Change it to:

```py
# Escape the \ with another \
normal_z.to_csv(os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + '\\Desktop\\normal_z.csv')

# Use raw string
normal_z.to_csv(os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + r'\Desktop\normal_z.csv')

# An even better way is to use pathlib and Unix-style path
from pathlib import Path
normal_z.to_csv(Path('~/Desktop/normal_z.csv').resolve())
```